# image return by jQuery/Ajax select change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Actually i'm facing problem to return the image that is associate with the select value. Code like:

```
<select class="pt-select" name="ptscrollbar_options[maptypeid]">
<option value="ROADMAP" <?php selected( $settings['maptypeid'], 'ROADMAP' ); ?>>ROADMAP</option>
<option value="SATELLITE" <?php selected( $settings['maptypeid'], 'SATELLITE' ); ?>>SATELLITE</option>
<option value="HYBRID" <?php selected( $settings['maptypeid'], 'HYBRID' ); ?>>HYBRID</option>
<option value="TERRAIN" <?php selected( $settings['maptypeid'], 'TERRAIN' ); ?>>TERRAIN</option>
</select>
```

My target is to change the image when i change the select value. Like if i select "SATELLITE" then immediately it will show a satellite image (from directory) or if i select "HYBRID" it will show another image. I tried though my ajax/jQuery knowledge is not the best but still unsuccessful.

Comment: store image path in option as custom attribute like rel="imagepath". Then on change you can retrieve image path like: $("option:selected",this).attr("rel");

Comment: Thanks @SandeepPal  . It will be my pleasure if u give a example because i am not so good in jQuery.

Comment: Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep_pal/vS7Yb/. You will have your actual image path in rel and instead of storing image in span tag, you will replace src in image tag

Comment: Is it possible to make default value output stable. Like if my default selected value is "ROADMAP" then it shows the output. Because now when i change then it shows the output of a value . @SandeepPal

Comment: Everything ok but the output shows only text means the image path url not image in <img src="source.png"/>. I tried but it shows the link as a text only not in img tag and doesn't show the image. Could u help me ?

Comment: Please use full image path in rel attribute.check this fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep_pal/vS7Yb/4/